# Является ли строка палиндромом си

Tags: c, строки

Не понимаю, почему программа для любой строки выводит, что она НЕ является палиндромом.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    char input[SIZE], s[SIZE];
    int len = 0, i= 0, j = 0, flag = 1;
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &input);
    len = strlen(input);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] != ' ')
        {
            s[j] = input[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    s[j] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        if (s[i] != s[len - i])
            flag = 0;

    if (flag)
        printf("Palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("Not palindrome\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: len - i - 1 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83

Answer (score 2):

Вам уже подсказали, что символы строки имеют номера от 0 до `strlen(s)-1`, что у вас не учтено. Кроме того, вы выбрасываете пробелы - а значит, длина вашей строки `s` запросто может быть меньше, чем посчитанное для входной строки `len` - а вы работаете именно с ним, не пересчитывая заново для новой строки `s`... Тут вам лучше было бы работать

```
for (i = 0; i < j / 2; i++)
    if (s[i] != s[j-1-i])
```

Но еще вы сравниваете все пары - а смысл, если первые же символы разные? Я бы делал примерно так, не проверяя ВСЕ символы, если дело плохо...

```
bool is_palindrome(char* s)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
        if (s[i] != s[j]) return false;
    return true;
}
```